# Coherent State Expansion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

We can expand a coherent state in terms of the number (Fock) states. I have two questions:

1. Is the reverse legitimate? I mean can we expand a number state in terms of coherent states?
2. If so, the eigenvalue of coherent state $α$ has a real part and an imaginary part. If I assume the imaginary part is zero, is the expansion still legitimate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can represent any state as a superposition of coherent state. You just use the resolution of identity,
$$\hat{I}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{\mathbb{C}}d^2\alpha|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|$$
to get,
$$|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{\mathbb{C}}d^2\alpha|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|n\rangle$$
For $|n\rangle$ that gives,
$$|n\rangle=\int\limits_{\mathbb{C}}d^2\alpha e^{-\frac{|\alpha|^2}{2}}\frac{(\alpha^\ast)^n}{\pi\sqrt{n!}}|\alpha\rangle$$

Note that coherent states form overcomplete basis i.e. this expansion is not unique.

The second part of your question I didn't understand, please clarify.

Comment: Thank you. In the second part, I mean $$\alpha|$$ has a real part and an imaginary part. If I assume the imaginary part is zero, is the expansion still legitimate?

Comment: @Farhad So, whether coherent states with only real $\alpha$ form (over)complete basis? I'd say, no. However I'm not yet ready to provide the proof.